# Can you make properties enumerable but not iterable in javascript?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

I was just wondering if there is a way to make an object property enumerable like in a `for in` loop but not show up in a `for of loop` sort of like

```
Object.defineProperty({},'prop',{
    enumerable:true,
    iterable:false
}
```

if not, are there any plans to implement a feature like this? Or does the `for of` loop use the enumerable property

Comment: I have googled it... I haven't found anything suggesting that there will be an attribute with that exact name. I just wondering if they're are any plans to implement a way to make values iteratable and keys not enumberable, I'll update my question to make that a little more clear

Comment: then you're probably asking in the wrong place. Asking on the ES6 mailing lists is far more likely to give you answer you want. Stackoverflow's foremost about asking code questions with code answers.

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans No need to be rude about it. Attitude aside, there's nothing off-topic about this question. We saw tons of similar questions when C++11 was being formed.

Answer (score 5):

I did some digging around at the Mozilla Development Network (MDN).

Turns out that objects have a `obj.propertyIsEnumerable(prop)` method to check if the property is enumerable. From the examples given in the MDN, properties inherited through the prototype chain are not enumerable, thus the method returns false for those properties.

An example of non enumerable properties are constructors and the property `length` of arrays.

For the iterable part of the question, I will quote MDN: "Iterable in ECMAScript 6 is an interface (or in other words, a protocol), not a type of object like Array or Map".

That is to say, the object needs to implement this interface to make its properties iterable. This is the case for built in iterables such as String, Array, Map, Set, WeakSet and Generator objects.

The following code illustrated this:

```
var aString = "hello"
typeof aString[Symbol.iterator] // "function"
aString[Symbol.iterator]() + "" // "[object String Iterator]"
[...aString]                    // ["h", "e", "l", "l", "o"]
```

Of course, you can define your own iterator implementation.

Coming back to the question, properties attached to the object or its prototype (directly, meaning not via inheritance) will be displayed as enumerable in the `for...in` loop. For the iterables you need an implementation, either the ones mentioned before, or your own. Here is a great example from MDN.

```
let arr = [ 3, 5, 7 ];
arr.foo = "hello";

for (let i in arr) {
   console.log(i); // logs "0", "1", "2", "foo" these are property names or indexes
}

for (let i of arr) {
   console.log(i); // logs "3", "5", "7" these are actual values of an
                   // iterable implementation provided by the array prototype
}
```

The `let` keyword is equivalent in this context to a `var` definition (though it has more implications but they are outside the scope of this post).

As you can see the array has an implementation already of the `iterable` interface (from the array prototype), thus it yields its values when using the `for...of` loop, whereas the `foo` property is not displayed (neither value nor property name).

So if your object does not implement an `iterable` interface, it should not be iterable (in principle) and thus it will display its properties' in a `for...of` loop.

Answer (score 2):

The difference between [`for in` and `for of` evaluations](http://people.mozilla.org/~jorendorff/es6-draft.html#sec-for-in-and-for-of-statements) is that one uses `obj.[[enumerate]]` and the other uses `GetIterator(obj)` to determine the looped items. [`[[enumerate]]` does](http://people.mozilla.org/~jorendorff/es6-draft.html#sec-ordinary-object-internal-methods-and-internal-slots-enumerate) (unless `obj` is a Proxy)

> return an [Iterator object](http://people.mozilla.org/~jorendorff/es6-draft.html#sec-iterator-interface) whose `next` method iterates over all the String-valued keys of enumerable properties of `obj`.

[`GetIterator`](http://people.mozilla.org/~jorendorff/es6-draft.html#sec-getiterator) will (try to) call the [`@@iterate` method](http://people.mozilla.org/~jorendorff/es6-draft.html#sec-iterable-interface) - however, normal objects don't implement this interface.

So no property will show up in `for of` loops unless you explicitly state it:

```
function defineIterableProperty(obj, prop, desc) {
    let old = obj[Symbol.iterate];
    Object.defineProperty(obj, prop, desc);
    obj[Symbol.iterate] = function* () {
        if (old) yield* old.call(this);
        yield prop;
    };
    return obj;
}
```

<sub>(Untested, but I hope you get the idea)</sub>