# Why for .. in gets all the properties, but for .. of doesn't get all the values?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

I tested the following code:

```
arr = [3, 5, 7];

arr.foo = "hello";

arr["boo"] ="moo"


for (i in arr) {
   console.log(i);
}

for (i of arr) {
   console.log(i); 
}
```

for .. in gets **all** the properties of the array.

```
for (i in arr) {
   console.log(i); 
}
```

returns:

```
0 
1 
2 
foo 
boo
```

but for .. of doesn't get all the values

```
  for (i of arr) {
       console.log(i); 
    }
```

returns:

```
3
5
7
```

What is the technical reason for this difference and why was this  apparent inconsistency accepted as default behavior?

Comment: Why *would* they be the same? They're two different operators, useful for two different behaviors.

Comment: http://andrewdupont.net/2006/05/18/javascript-associative-arrays-considered-harmful/

Comment: @Bergi The article covers some of my points really well.

Comment: @EduardFlorinescu: I can't see you were making any points :-) `for of` does not enumerate all property values, it iterates elements - which for an array are only array elements.

Comment: @sphanley I never said or implied same, you can see if you read the title I mention properties vs values, I  would have expected similar behavior but I don't imply same anywhere.

Comment: Related: [Why are Objects not Iterable in JavaScript?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/29886552/1048572) and [Can you make properties enumerable but not iterable in javascript?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/24877452/1048572)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `for (... in ...)` syntax is available for use on any object, and will iterate over all properties of that object. More technically, this loop will iterate over any property in the object that's internally defined with its `[[Enumerbale]]` property set to true.

The `for (... of ...)` syntax is new with ES6, and is specific to **collections**, rather than all objects. It provides a shorthand way to iterate over the elements of a collection, rather than having to use a plain `for` or `while` loop with an index. It will iterate in this manner over any the elements of any collection that has a `[Symbol.iterator]` property.

This isn't an "inconsistency", they're two different operators intended to be used for two different purposes. I can understand how it might seem like doing something like `arr["boo"] ="moo"` would add an element to the array -- since you can access the array's elements via a similar syntax, as in `arr[0]`. But it's easy to confirm that those aren't the same in effect - with `arr["boo"] ="moo"` you're creating a property that can also be accessed by `arr.boo`, but attempting to access the elements of an array by, say, `arr.0` would be a syntax error, because they aren't the same as properties.

Answer (score 2):

You're trying to treat the array as though it were an object, or an associative array (not a thing in JavaScript).

It's an array; non-integer properties are never going to be values of the array, which is what `for...of` will get you.

You're adding bonus properties to the `arr` object, but expecting the value of `arr.foo` to show up in `for..of` would be like expecting the value of `arr.length` to show up.

Comment: That's because arr["length"] is the same as arr.length in JavaScript

Comment: but there could have been ways to know if some properties are legacy of the Object/Array etc or just defined by the user